# How to get a proceeding item that may be in another node?

Tags: xml, xslt

With the sample XML:

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <items>
            <item>1</item>
            <item>2</item>
        </items>
    </order>
    <order>
        <items>
            <item>3</item>
            <item>4</item>
        </items>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I am currently rendering out a spreadsheet that essentially makes  a top level.  I'm doing this through an apply-templates, where I have

```
<apply-templates match="orders/order/items/item"><!-- sorts --></apply-templates>
```

I want to apply a header whenever a certain attribute in the item changes, how would I get the previous item?

for item4, I think I could use `preceding-sibling::item` to get item3, but if my active node was item3, how would I get item2?

I'm currently assuming I'll need to set this to a variable with a choose, something like:

```
<xslt:variable name="previousItem">
    <xslt:choose>
        <xslt:when test="count(preceding-sibling::item)">
            <xslt:value-of match="preceding-sibling::item" />
        </xslt:when>
        <xslt:otherwise>
            <!-- some logic here -->
        </xslt:otherwise>
    </xslt:choose>
</xslt:variable>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] where the items actually have "a certain attribute", and include the expected output. -- Note that `<xslt:value-of match="::prceding-sibling" />` is not valid XSLT syntax, on several counts. And neither is `count(::preceding-sibling)`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I meant that to be part of the scope of the question, and have modified the grammar to clarify

Comment: Your question, as I understand it. is about "*I want to apply a header whenever a certain attribute in the item changes*". This is a *grouping* problem - and the code you have posted has very little to do with it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: That's only my reason for wanting to do that, my question is how to get the previous item so that I can do the grouping - unless XSLT 1.0 has some alternative functionality I'm not aware about that I should be asking about instead?

Comment: You should study: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `preceding::item[1]`. It only selects items that occurs before the current element.

Comment: But if item3 was our currently focused item, that would return nothing instead of returning item2, right?

Comment: @Navarr: No, `preceding::item[1]` from `//item[.=3]` is `//item[.=2]`.

Comment: Oh!  I've spent so much time looking at the text preceding-sibling, It didn't even register that you had used preceding.